# Deadlocks - Finding full SQL statement from deadlock report

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

I have an application running against a SQL Server 2016 database that is causing deadlocks.

The deadlock graph shows me the Objectid and Object name of the underlying object.   It also provides with a truncated SQL statement.

However, some of the statements are quite big and exceed what appears to be a 1024 character limit in the XML deadlock report for the `<inputbuf>` entity.  I'd like to be able to review the full statements involved in these locks so I can reproduce and debug the issue.

[image]

Is there a way this limit can be increased, or can is there a method to find the full SQL statement given the transaction descriptor which is included in the deadlock graph?

Comment: @masoud Do you have an extended event running for monitoring deadlocks?

Comment: @Otter: No, I’m using SQL Server Profiler to generate deadlock graph

Comment: I think your best bet is to use an extended event session, it is much more lightweight and offers more useful information. You can then parse that file using something like [this](https://gist.github.com/Otterpohl/d94b42f8e530bc473edb9965f0104c92)

Comment: The deadlock graph / XDL contains the SQL handle which is what I was looking for.  
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text( sql_handle)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sql-text-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that I could obtain the full SQL text of each query in the deadlock using the SQL Handle string (the SQL Handle is included in the deadlock graph / XDL).

For example, within the Deadlock XML:

```
<frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="368" sqlhandle="0x02000000309a63065dbc0db09405222fe0f66eb954ed1d870000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
```

Pass sqlhandle to sys.dm_exec_sql_text

```
 SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(0x02000000309a63065dbc0db09405222fe0f66eb954ed1d870000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) -- modify this value with your actual sql_handle
```

Comment: Thank you, but this work only if the plan for that query be in cache.  `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` get the handle of the query more recently executed, but the plan for a query may no longer be in cache. And then there a lot of system processes of which the handle is 0x0. I'm looking for a way to get full text sql for any time executed queries :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with code objects such as Stored Procedures you could easily find them with third-party tools.
some of the free ones that saved me a ton of time in the past.
free plugin for SSMS.

- [ApexSQL Search](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-search.aspx).
- Redgate's [SQL Search](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/).

or you could find by this code -

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Sharon
-- Create date: 12/10/2014
-- Description: FindObject
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_FindObject]
    @Text         NVARCHAR(4000),
    @DatabaseName sysname,
    @Table        BIT = 1,
    @Column       BIT = 1,
    @View         BIT = 1,
    @Function     BIT = 1,
    @Procedure    BIT = 1,
    @Trigger      BIT = 1,
    @Constreint   BIT = 1,
    @Job          BIT = 0,
    @ReportServer BIT = 0,
    @IsExactMatch BIT = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    DECLARE @IsAllDatabases BIT = 0;
    DECLARE @Print NVARCHAR(2048) = N'';
    DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';



    IF @Text IS NULL
        RAISERROR('Insert text to look for!', 16, 1);

    IF @IsExactMatch IS NULL
        SET @IsExactMatch = 0;
    IF IIF(@Table IS NULL, 0, @Table) + IIF(@Column IS NULL, 0, @Column) + IIF(@View IS NULL, 0, @View)
       + IIF(@Function IS NULL, 0, @Function) + IIF(@Procedure IS NULL, 0, @Procedure)
       + IIF(@Trigger IS NULL, 0, @Trigger) + IIF(@Constreint IS NULL, 0, @Constreint) > 0
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (   SELECT    TOP (1)  1
                          FROM      sys.databases
                          WHERE     name = @DatabaseName)
        BEGIN
            SET @IsAllDatabases = 1;
            CREATE TABLE #DBResult
                 (   [Database Name] sysname       NULL,
                     [Object Schema] sysname       NULL,
                     [Object Name]   sysname       NULL,
                     [Object Type]   sysname       NULL,
                     [TEXT Location] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
                     [Position]      NVARCHAR(1000)
                 );
            DECLARE curDatabases CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
            SELECT  d.name
            FROM    master.sys.databases d
            WHERE   d.state = 0 --ONLINE
                    AND d.database_id > 4
                    AND HAS_DBACCESS(d.name) = 1  -- Have access
                    AND DATABASEPROPERTYEX(d.name, 'Updateability') = 'READ_WRITE'
                    AND NOT EXISTS
                      (
                        SELECT  TOP (1) 1 
                        FROM    sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states AS drs 
                                INNER JOIN sys.availability_replicas AS ar ON ar.replica_id = drs.replica_id
                                INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states ags ON ags.group_id = ar.group_id
                          WHERE drs.database_id = d.database_id
                                AND ar.secondary_role_allow_connections = 0
                                AND ags.primary_replica <> CONVERT(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName'))
                      );
        END;
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            
            DECLARE curDatabases CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
            SELECT  d.name
            FROM    master.sys.databases d
            WHERE   d.state = 0 --ONLINE
                    AND d.database_id > 4
                    AND HAS_DBACCESS(d.name) = 1  -- Have access
                    AND DATABASEPROPERTYEX(d.name, 'Updateability') = 'READ_WRITE'
                    AND NOT EXISTS
                      (
                        SELECT  TOP (1) 1 
                        FROM    sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states AS drs 
                                INNER JOIN sys.availability_replicas AS ar ON ar.replica_id = drs.replica_id
                                INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states ags ON ags.group_id = ar.group_id
                          WHERE drs.database_id = d.database_id
                                AND ar.secondary_role_allow_connections = 0
                                AND ags.primary_replica <> CONVERT(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName'))
                      )
                    AND d.name = @DatabaseName;
            CREATE TABLE #Result
                 (
                     [Object Schema] sysname       NULL,
                     [Object Name]   sysname       NULL,
                     [Object Type]   sysname       NULL,
                     [TEXT Location] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
                     [Position]      NVARCHAR(1000)
                 );
        END
            -- Table names
            IF @Table = 1
            BEGIN



                OPEN curDatabases;

                FETCH NEXT FROM curDatabases INTO @DatabaseName;

                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN
                SET @cmd = CONCAT(IIF(@DatabaseName IS NOT NULL,N'USE [' + @DatabaseName + '];',N''),N'
INSERT #',IIF(@IsAllDatabases = 1,'DB',''),'Result
SELECT ',IIF(@IsAllDatabases = 1,'DB_NAME(),',''),'TABLE_SCHEMA  AS [Object Schema]
        ,TABLE_NAME    AS [Object Name]
        ,TABLE_TYPE    AS [Object Type]
        ,''Table Name''  AS [TEXT Location]
        ,NULL
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE   TABLE_TYPE = N''BASE TABLE''
        AND  TABLE_NAME LIKE ''%''+@Text+''%''');
                    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@Text nvarchar(4000)', @Text = @Text;
                    SET @Print = CONCAT('Search Table on ',@DatabaseName,' complete.');
                    RAISERROR (@Print, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
                    FETCH NEXT FROM curDatabases INTO @DatabaseName;
                END

                CLOSE curDatabases;
                
            END;

            --Column names| computed_columns
            IF @Column = 1
            BEGIN

                OPEN curDatabases;

                FETCH NEXT FROM curDatabases INTO @DatabaseName;

                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN

                SET @cmd = CONCAT(IIF(@DatabaseName IS NOT NULL,N'USE [' + @DatabaseName + '];',N''),N'
INSERT #',IIF(@IsAllDatabases = 1,'DB',''),'Result
SELECT  ',IIF(@IsAllDatabases = 1,'DB_NAME(),',''),'TABLE_SCHEMA AS [Object Schema]
        ,TABLE_NAME   AS [Object Name]
        ,''COLUMN''      AS [Object Type]
        ,COLUMN_NAME AS [TEXT Location]
        ,NULL
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE ''%''+@Text+''%''
UNION ALL 

SELECT  ',IIF(@IsAllDatabases = 1,'DB_NAME(),',''),'s.name AS [Object Schema]
        ,o.name       AS [Object Name]
        ,o.type_desc       AS [Object Type]
        ,C.definition AS [TEXT Location]
        ,NULL
FROM    sys.computed_columns C
        INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON C.object_id = o.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE   C.definition Like ''%''+@Text+''%''
')              ;

                    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@Text nvarchar(4000)', @Text = @Text;
                    SET @Print = CONCAT('Search Column on ',@DatabaseName,' complete.');
                    RAISERROR (@Print, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

                    FETCH NEXT FROM curDatabases INTO @DatabaseName;
                END

                CLOSE curDatabases;
            END;

            --PROCEDURE
            IF @Procedure = 1
            BEGIN
            
                OPEN curDatabases;

                FETCH NEXT FROM curDatabases INTO @DatabaseName;

                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN

                SET @cmd = CONCAT(
                               N'INSERT #',IIF(@IsAllDatabases = 1,'DB',''),'Result
SELECT  ',IIF(@IsAllDatabases = 1,'DB_NAME(),',''),'s.name AS [Object Schema]
        ,o.name       AS [Object Name]
        ,''PROCEDURE'' AS [Object Type]
        ,m.definition AS [TEXT Location]
        ,SUBSTRING(m.definition,PATINDEX(''%''+@Text+''%'',m.definition),100)
FROM    sys.sql_modules m 
        INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE   m.definition Like ''%''+@Text+''%''
        and o.type = ''P''');

                    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@Text nvarchar(4000)', @Text = @Text;
                    SET @Print = CONCAT('Search Procedure on ',@DatabaseName,' complete.');
                    RAISERROR (@Print, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

                    FETCH NEXT FROM curDatabases INTO @DatabaseName;
                END

                CLOSE curDatabases;
            END;


            -- FUNCTION
            IF @Function = 1
            BEGIN

                OPEN curDatabases;

                FETCH NEXT FROM curDatabases INTO @DatabaseName;

                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN

                SET @cmd = CONCAT(
                               N'INSERT #',IIF(@IsAllDatabases = 1,'DB',''),'Result
SELECT  ',IIF(@IsAllDatabases = 1,'DB_NAME(),',''),'s.name AS [Object Schema]
        ,o.name       AS [Object Name]
        ,''FUNCTION('' + o.type + '')'' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [Object Type]
        ,m.definition AS [TEXT Location]
        ,SUBSTRING(m.definition,PATINDEX(''%''+@Text+''%'',m.definition),100)
FROM    sys.sql_modules m 
        INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE   m.definition Like ''%''+@Text+''%''
        and o.type in (''FN'',''AF'',''FS'',''FT'',''IF'',''TF'')');

                    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@Text nvarchar(4000)', @Text = @Text;
                    SET @Print = CONCAT('Search Function on ',@DatabaseName,' complete.');
                    RAISERROR (@Print, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

                    FETCH NEXT FROM curDatabases INTO @DatabaseName;
                END

                CLOSE curDatabases;
            END;
            -- Trigger
            IF @Trigger = 1
            BEGIN
            
                OPEN curDatabases;

                FETCH NEXT FROM curDatabases INTO @DatabaseName;

                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN

                SET @cmd = CONCAT(
                               N'INSERT #',IIF(@IsAllDatabases = 1,'DB',''),'Result
SELECT  ',IIF(@IsAllDatabases = 1,'DB_NAME(),',''),'s.name AS [Object Schema]
        ,o.name       AS [Object Name]
        ,''FUNCTION('' + o.type + '')'' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [Object Type]
        ,m.definition AS [TEXT Location]
        ,SUBSTRING(m.definition,PATINDEX(''%''+@Text+''%'',m.definition),100)
FROM    sys.sql_modules m 
        INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE   m.definition Like ''%''+@Text+''%''
        and o.type = ''TR''');

                    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@Text nvarchar(4000)', @Text = @Text;
                    SET @Print = CONCAT('Search Trigger on ',@DatabaseName,' complete.');
                    RAISERROR (@Print, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

                    FETCH NEXT FROM curDatabases INTO @DatabaseName;
                END

                CLOSE curDatabases;
            END;
            --View
            IF @View = 1
            BEGIN
            
                OPEN curDatabases;

                FETCH NEXT FROM curDatabases INTO @DatabaseName;

                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN

                SET @cmd = CONCAT(
                               N'INSERT #',IIF(@IsAllDatabases = 1,'DB',''),'Result
SELECT  ',IIF(@IsAllDatabases = 1,'DB_NAME(),',''),'s.name AS [Object Schema]
        ,o.name       AS [Object Name]
        ,o.type_desc COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [Object Type]
        ,m.definition AS [TEXT Location]
        ,SUBSTRING(m.definition,PATINDEX(''%''+@Text+''%'',m.definition),100)
FROM    sys.sql_modules m 
        INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE   m.definition Like ''%''+@Text+''%''
        and o.type = ''v''');

                    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@Text nvarchar(4000)', @Text = @Text;
                    SET @Print = CONCAT('Search View on ',@DatabaseName,' complete.');
                    RAISERROR (@Print, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

                    FETCH NEXT FROM curDatabases INTO @DatabaseName;
                END

                CLOSE curDatabases;
            END;

            --default_constraints| check_constraints
            IF @Constreint = 1
            BEGIN
            
                OPEN curDatabases;

                FETCH NEXT FROM curDatabases INTO @DatabaseName;

                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN

                SET @cmd = CONCAT(
                               N'INSERT #',IIF(@IsAllDatabases = 1,'DB',''),'Result
SELECT  ',IIF(@IsAllDatabases = 1,'DB_NAME(),',''),'s.name AS [Object Schema]
        ,o.name       AS [Object Name]
        ,o.type_desc       AS [Object Type]
        ,D.definition AS [TEXT Location]
        ,SUBSTRING(D.definition,PATINDEX(''%''+@Text+''%'',D.definition),100)
FROM    sys.default_constraints D
        INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON D.object_id = o.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE   D.definition Like ''%''+@Text+''%''
UNION ALL 
SELECT  ',IIF(@IsAllDatabases = 1,'DB_NAME(),',''),'s.name AS [Object Schema]
        ,o.name       AS [Object Name]
        ,o.type_desc       AS [Object Type]
        ,C.definition AS [TEXT Location]
        ,SUBSTRING(D.definition,PATINDEX(''%''+@Text+''%'',C.definition),100)
FROM    sys.check_constraints C
        INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON C.object_id = o.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE   C.definition Like ''%''+@Text+''%''');

                    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@Text nvarchar(4000)', @Text = @Text;
                    SET @Print = CONCAT('Search Constreint on ',@DatabaseName,' complete.');
                    RAISERROR (@Print, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

                    FETCH NEXT FROM curDatabases INTO @DatabaseName;
                END

                CLOSE curDatabases;
            END;


            
            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DBResult') IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                SELECT  *
                FROM    #DBResult
                WHERE   @IsExactMatch = 0
                        OR (@IsExactMatch = 1 AND [Object Name] = @Text);
                DROP TABLE #DBResult;
            END 
            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Result') IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                SELECT  *
                FROM    #Result
                WHERE   @IsExactMatch = 0
                        OR (@IsExactMatch = 1 AND [Object Name] = @Text);
                DROP TABLE #Result;
            END

        END;
    END;
    -- Job
    IF @Job = 1
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @PreviewTextSize INT = 100;

        SELECT  'Job Steps'                AS SearchType,
                j.[name]                   AS [Job Name],
                s.step_id                  AS [Step #],
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        SUBSTRING(s.command, CHARINDEX(@Text, s.command) - @PreviewTextSize / 2, @PreviewTextSize),
                        CHAR(13) + CHAR(10),
                        ''),
                    @Text,
                    '***' + @Text + '***') AS Command
        FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobs                j
                INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps s ON j.job_id = s.job_id
        WHERE   s.command LIKE '%' + @Text + '%';
    END;
    -- SSRS
    IF @ReportServer = 1
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'ReportServer')
        BEGIN;
            WITH cte AS
                (
                --gets the RDL; note the double convert.
                SELECT  [Path],
                        [Name]                                         AS Report_Name,
                        CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Content)) AS rdl
                FROM    ReportServer.dbo.Catalog)
            SELECT      LEFT([Path], LEN([Path]) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE([Path])) + 1)           AS Report_Path,
                        Report_Name,
                        T1.N.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(128)')                                      AS DataSetName,
                        T2.N.value('(*:DataSourceName/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')               AS DataSourceName,
                        ISNULL(T2.N.value('(*:CommandType/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(128)'), 'T-SQL') AS CommandType,
                        T2.N.value('(*:CommandText/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')                  AS CommandText
            INTO        #SSRS
            FROM        cte                                                       AS T
                        CROSS APPLY T.rdl.nodes('/*:Report/*:DataSets/*:DataSet') AS T1(N)
                        CROSS APPLY T1.N.nodes('*:Query') AS T2(N)
            ORDER BY    Report_Path,
                        Report_Name,
                        DataSetName,
                        DataSourceName,
                        CommandType,
                        CommandText;

            SELECT  *
            FROM    #SSRS
            WHERE   CommandText LIKE '%' + @Text + '%';
        END;
        
    DEALLOCATE curDatabases;
END;
```

But, if you are working with [EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) o [Nhibernate](https://nhibernate.info/) you are in a tough spot

Comment: Thanks for that but I'm actually looking for the full SQL statement (rather than an object in the DB) that caused the deadlock.  In Oracle, this could be the SQL_Text garnered from searching for the supplied SQL_ID of a session.  I suspect the "Transaction Descriptor" is SQL Server's alternative to the SQL_ID but I can't find a way of pulling any information from it.